# How can a Pandas series be grouped by datetime week (not ordinal) over several years

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas series in this format spanning several years:

```
2013-01-03 00:00:00+00:00   -0.002190
2013-01-04 00:00:00+00:00    0.004185
2013-01-07 00:00:00+00:00   -0.002835
2013-01-08 00:00:00+00:00   -0.002912
2013-01-09 00:00:00+00:00    0.002817
2013-01-10 00:00:00+00:00    0.007674
2013-01-11 00:00:00+00:00    0.000272
...
```

I'm trying to aggregate on a weekly basis, however using the groupby week method returns an ordinal which seems to be limited to 52 weeks, such as in the below function:

```
#convert to weekly value
def weekly_mean(series):
    grouped = series.groupby(lambda x: x.week)
    return grouped.aggregate(np.mean)
```

How can I have a weekly grouping that is either datetime indexed or not limited to 52 entries?

Comment: Are you asking to group on year and week ordinal? if so then `grouped = series.groupby([series.index,year, series.index.week])` should work

Comment: You could use resample with a new frequency of 7 days